# How to get rest api pagination headers via fetch

Tags: pagination, rest-api, headers

I'm creating a react app via create-react-app. My application is very simple, I just want to fetch posts and display the images and the post title. I can't seem to be able to get the pagination portion of the headers. Here's my code and the response will follow:

```
fetch('https://example.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed')
      .then(res => console.log('the response::::::::', res) || res)
      .then(response => response.json())
```

the response logged with 'the response:::::::':

```
Response {type: "cors", url: "https://example.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "https://example.com/index.php/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed"
__proto__: Response
```

As you can see headers seem to be an empty object (other than the proto)...

Am I missing something? This is just straigh wordpress, no plugins or anything other than the default theme.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `res.headers.get("X-WP-TotalPages")` or `res.headers.get("X-WP-Total")` to get the header values. See the [MDN Fetch documentation's Headers section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#headers).

Comment: That's how it should work, yes, but you can see in the question OP's response headers array is empty.

Comment: This works for me. I was getting an empty headers object, too. But in inspector > Fetch/XHR under Headers tab I was able to see the X-WP-TotalPages value.

Answer (score 0):

To help others looking for this answer - if you're already working within React with the WordPress package, you can use the [apiFetch](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/) and [addQueryArgs](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-url/#addqueryargs) utilities.

```
import apiFetch from '@wordpress/api-fetch';
import { addQueryArgs } from '@wordpress/url';

const args = {
    page: 1,
    _embed: true // to get all of the additional image info
};

// Using apiFetch with the parse argument set to false allows us to get the headers
apiFetch( { path: addQueryArgs( '/wp/v2/posts', args ), parse: false } )
.then( ( res ) => {
    console.log( 'Result:', res );
    console.log( `There are ${res.headers.get( 'X-WP-Total' )} total results in the collection.` );
    console.log( `You're on page ${args.page} of ${res.headers.get( 'X-WP-TotalPages' )}.` );

    // Return the Promise (which will resolve as posts)
    return res.json();
})
.then( ( posts ) => {
    console.log( 'Posts:', posts );

    // Do something with posts

    // Example of grabbing the post thumbnails (_embed: true needs to be an argument for the _embedded data to be returned in the REST result)
    for ( let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++ ) {
        if ( posts[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'].length ) {
            console.log( `${posts[i].title.rendered} image: ${posts[i]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].media_details.sizes['post-thumbnail'].source_url}` );
        }
    }
})
.catch( ( err ) => {
    console.error( err );
});
```